# proper way to update mongo array if only serving a portion of it?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection which contains an array of `games` a player is playing. However, I limit the view each user has of that player's games to only games they also play in my publication.

```
Meteor.publish('Player.profile', function (playerId, gameId) {
  check(playerId, String);
  if (this.userId) {
    var games = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).profile().games;
    if(!_.contains(games, gameId)) {
      return [];
    }

    return Players.find({
      _id: playerId,
      games: {
        $elemMatch: {
          _id: gameId
        }
      }
    }, {
      fields: {
        "battletag": 1,
        "games.$": 1
      }
    });
  }
  return [];
});
```

This will only show a single field of the array.

However, when I am updating this on the client, how does one properly update it, knowing that only one field of many are visible to the client?

Comment: Use a [server method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods)?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to update. Are you trying to allow one user to update another user's "games" field?